# Record error after insert, conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: sql

I'm trying to insert records into a table via a sql management studio and insert command verses the website's web form.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Records] ([tp_ID], [Offense_ID], [LLO_ID], [LLLA], [SSN], [LastName], [FirstName], [MI], [Title], [Grade], [Organization], [BranchOfService],  [Category], [DateCategory],  [IsHoldover], [IsHoldoverDate])
VALUES (60033, N'E', 17, NULL, N'222-12-0222', N'SINGER', N'Te ', N'Y', NULL, N'SrA', N'703 Airbase', N'FORCE', NULL, NULL)
```

Although when I go to the website and try to view the record I recieve the following error message:

System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid.

```
Line 349:ckIsHoldOver.Checked = (CInt(rdr("IsHoldover")) = -1)
```

---vb in the code behind that caputures the field data if i create a record through the web form---

```
 .Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsHoldover", ckIsHoldOver.Checked)
```

Comment: The error makes sense, based on your input statement, the IsHoldOver field is getting a NULL, so the .NET code can't convert a NULL to an integer...   Not sure what the question is, it appears everything is working as it should...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rdr("IsHoldover")` is `NULL`, therefore when converting to integer using `CInt()`, this is causing an exception.

You can either change your `INSERT` statement to insert a `Non-NULL` `bit` value (`1` or `0`), or change your VB code to take into account this nullable field:

```
If Not IsDBNULL(rdr("IsHolderover")) Then ckIsHoldOver.Checked = (CInt(rdr("IsHoldover")) = -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is here.  You *are* inserting a null value into IsHoldOver, and on the website you're trying to convert that null to an integer.

Maybe try putting a value in IsHoldOver instead

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Records] ([tp_ID], [Offense_ID], [LLO_ID], [LLLA], [SSN], [LastName], [FirstName], [MI], [Title], [Grade], [Organization], [BranchOfService],  [Category], [DateCategory],  [IsHoldover], [IsHoldoverDate])
VALUES (60033, N'E', 17, NULL, N'222-12-0222', N'SINGER', N'Te ', N'Y', NULL, N'SrA', N'703 Airbase', N'FORCE', 0, NULL)
```

or handle nulls on the web page as Curt shows you how to do below.